# How send to email using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
    $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.tch-pnt.in";  //
    $config['smtp_port'] = 587;
    $config['smtp_user'] = "bnft@tch-pnt.in";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "********";
    $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
    $config['mailtype'] = "html";
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
```

Error...
I am using above configuration setup for sending email...

No error but i am not getting  mails in my inbox.I tried 3 times.

I used default port as 25 still no mails

Comment: If not used ssl before server url  no erro.............

Comment: If use ssl  above...errorMessage: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try

```
$config['smtp_host'] = "sslv2://smtp.tch-pnt.in";
```

or try port number 465.